# How can I Encode String , ByteArray in ActionScript as VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, actionscript-3, apache-flex, sha256

I want to **hash password** using **mx.utils.SHA256** or `SHA256` algo based password in `ActionScript` for my `SQLite` local database hashed password. So that I can match the inserted password with the database stored `HashedPassword`. For this I am using `Salt` too.

I want the same things with `ActionScript` which I have done in `VB` code.

**How can I change the following in `ActionScript` from `VB.NET`?**

```
 Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("String")
```

`String Salt` - type parameter.

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Salt.ToString.ToCharArray))
```

`byte HashOut` - type parameter.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(HashOut)
```

`Array.Copy()` method `Copies` one Byte Array to another according to specified length:

```
 Array.Copy(Data, DataAndSalt, Data.Length) // concatenation of Arrays in context of `ActionScript`
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `Encoding.Default` for anything which is meant to be portable anyway...

Comment: Language note: SHA is **hashing**, not encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Created the whole code according to my requirements Own My Own , Which was done in the VB  and now both are producing the same results .

- `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("String")` VB code in ActionScript is
  **`yourByteArray.writeMultiByte("String", "iso-8859-1");`**
- `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Salt.ToString.ToCharArray))` 
  VB code in ActionScript is

  **`byterrSalt.writeMultiByte(Salt,Salt);`**
- `Array.Copy(Data, DataAndSalt, Data.Length)`

  it was for **concatenation of byte array** which has been done in
  actions script is done by

**`var DataAndSalt:ByteArray = new ByteArray();`**

**`DataAndSalt.writeBytes(Data);`**

**`DataAndSalt.writeBytes(Salt);`**

**DataAndSalt ByteArray Will have both byteArray now Data + Salt**

**Data is ByteArray** and you can Concatenate Many Byte Arrays  by **.writeBytes(YourByteArray)**

- . `Convert.ToBase64String(HashOut)` is done By the following fucntion

  ```
  private static const BASE64_CHARS:String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";



  public static function encodeByteArray(data:ByteArray):String {
          // Initialise output
          var output:String = "";

          // Create data and output buffers
          var dataBuffer:Array;
          var outputBuffer:Array = new Array(4);

          // Rewind ByteArray
          data.position = 0;

          // while there are still bytes to be processed
          while (data.bytesAvailable > 0) {
              // Create new data buffer and populate next 3 bytes from data
              dataBuffer = new Array();
              for (var i:uint = 0; i < 3 && data.bytesAvailable > 0; i++) {
                  dataBuffer[i] = data.readUnsignedByte();
              }

              // Convert to data buffer Base64 character positions and 
              // store in output buffer
              outputBuffer[0] = (dataBuffer[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
              outputBuffer[1] = ((dataBuffer[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((dataBuffer[1]) >> 4);
              outputBuffer[2] = ((dataBuffer[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | ((dataBuffer[2]) >> 6);
              outputBuffer[3] = dataBuffer[2] & 0x3f;

              // If data buffer was short (i.e not 3 characters) then set
              // end character indexes in data buffer to index of '=' symbol.
              // This is necessary because Base64 data is always a multiple of
              // 4 bytes and is basses with '=' symbols.
              for (var j:uint = dataBuffer.length; j < 3; j++) {
                  outputBuffer[j + 1] = 64;
              }

              // Loop through output buffer and add Base64 characters to 
              // encoded data string for each character.
              for (var k:uint = 0; k < outputBuffer.length; k++) {
                  output += BASE64_CHARS.charAt(outputBuffer[k]);
              }
          }

          // Return encoded data
          return output;

      }
  ```

Thank You

Udit Bhardwaj

Answer (score 2):

Fairly simple process, but the documentation of Actionscript's `SHA256` class is pretty lackluster, What you need to do is:

1. Write your salted string to a `ByteArray`
2. Call `SHA256.computeDigest()`

EG:

```
public function hashMyString(mySaltedInput:String):String
{
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
    bytes.writeUTFBytes(mySaltedInput):
    return SHA256.computeDigest(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, before calling `SHA256.computeDigest()`, I had to say: `bytes.position = 0;` or the resulting hash was incorrect.  Stepping through the code in `mx.utils.SHA256`, it looks like it tries to read back bytes from the `ByteArray` which, after the `String` has been written to it with `writeUTFBytes()`, has it's read position set to the end of the array.  So it still works, it just generates the wrong hash.  (With FLEX Builder 3, anyway.)